# Accessing current controller executing in DelegatingHandler

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I was wondering if it's possible to access the controller being executed (or about to be executed) in the SendAsync method of the DelegatingHandler?  I can't seem to figure out how to get access to it, and I figure it's because it executes outside of the controller execution...

Is it possible to refer to it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No, because message handlers operate on raw `HttpRequestMessage` or raw `HttpResponseMessage` (in case of continuations). So really, there is no concept of *"current controller executing"* with `DelegatingHandlers` since message handlers will be called before dispatching the request to the controller or (again, in the case of continuations) after the controller returns the reponse.

However, it really depends what you are trying to do.

If you want to know to which controller the request will end up getting routed, you can manually call the mechanism that would internally select the controllers.

```
public class MyHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override System.Threading.Tasks.Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;
        var controllerSelector = new DefaultHttpControllerSelector(config);

        // descriptor here will contain information about the controller to which the request will be routed. If it's null (i.e. controller not found), it will throw an exception
        var descriptor = controllerSelector.SelectController(request);

        // continue
        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have a validation routine, and it would be nice to be able to check the controller type to see if it has a custom attribute defined, so I can avoid this validation routine.  This should make that possible.

Comment: great. yes you can easily do that once you grab an instance of HttpControllerDescriptor

Comment: @FilipW is there a 'nice' way to do this without it throwing an exception? in the source code the call to `SelectController` ultimately calls `this._controllerInfoCache.Value.TryGetValue(controllerName, out controllerDescriptor)` however `_controllerInfoCache` is not accessible publicly in any way

Comment: In Web API 2 it is better to use the `request.GetConfiguration()` extension method instead of the `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration` reference.

Comment: Is this possible with Attribute Routing instead Config Routing?

Answer (score 4):

Extending the @GalacticBoy solution, it would be better to use

```
public class MyHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private static IHttpControllerSelector _controllerSelector = null;

    protected override System.Threading.Tasks.Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (_controllerSelector == null)
        {
            var config = request.GetConfiguration();
            _controllerSelector = config.Services.GetService(typeof(IHttpControllerSelector)) as IHttpControllerSelector;
        }

        try
        {
            // descriptor here will contain information about the controller to which the request will be routed. If it's null (i.e. controller not found), it will throw an exception
            var descriptor = _controllerSelector.SelectController(request);


        }
        catch
        {
            // controller not found
        }

        // continue
        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what your doing with the information maybe your fine with getting the information after the request is executed. For example logging the executed controller/action.

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;

namespace Example
{
    public class SampleHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken)
                       .ContinueWith(task =>
                       {
                           HttpResponseMessage response = task.Result;

                           string actionName = request.GetActionDescriptor().ActionName;
                           string controllerName = request.GetActionDescriptor().ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;

                            // log action/controller or do something else

                           return response;
                       }, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
}
```